# Multiple Arrays foreach statement

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, custom-fields

I am working on my first PHP Layout from my existing HTML. I am running in to trouble. I hope stackoverflow can help

I have 3 arrays

```
$parent = array('1' => 'parent1' , 'parent2' , 'parent3' , 'parent4' , );
$child = array('1' => 'child1' , 'child2' , 'child3' , 'child4' , );
$content = array('1' => 'content1' , 'content2' , 'content3' , 'content4' , );
```

I am trying to use them to make a repeating list which will include {$parent}, {$child}, and {$content} like the following..

```
<?php 
  echo "<h1 id='js-overview' class='page-header'>$parent</h1>"
  echo "<h3 id='js-fotopia'>$child</h3>" 
  echo "<p>$content</p>"
?>
```

but i need to run this for each of my variables. How do I write the statement? also how can I set it up so that the child and child content are also repeating. like in the pic

See the pic to understand my layout that i need to keep repeating as long as there are variables filled out... Please ask questions if i am not making since rather than skipping... I need php guidance.

[image: never mind the menu]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think your structure is a bit off.  Instead of 3 arrays, why not combine them into one?  It's a little unclear how the parent/child/content relationship you have is setup, but here's a shot:

```
$arr = array(
    'parent1' => array(
        'child1' => array(
            'content' => 'This is your content for child 1',
        ),
        'child2' => array(
            'content' => 'This is your content for child 2',
        ),
    ),
    'parent2' => array(
        'child1' => array(
            'content' => 'This is your content for child 1 inside of parent 2',
        )
    ),
);
```

Then you can just `foreach` over the array, and `foreach` over the children:

```
foreach($arr as $parent) {
    foreach($parent as $childName => $child) {
        echo $child['content'];
    }
}
```

You can add more keys into the children array if you need more structure to your content.

Comment: thanks... Used a version of this... I have a ways to go in php

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps something like this?

```
for($i=1; $i<=count($parent); $i++){
      echo "<h1 id='js-overview' class='page-header'>$parent[$i]</h1>"
      echo "<h3 id='js-fotopia'>$child[$i]</h3>" 
      echo "<p>$content[$i]</p>"
}
```

Alternatively you could use a `foreach` and assuming the keys line up like this syntax

`foreach (array_expression as $key => $value)
    statement`

Alternatively to that you could construct 1 2D array that stores the parent, child and content all in 1 row.